# SQL query whose blog id contains only the last 4 blogs of all blogs in the blog category matching that id

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck in one SQL query. I have two tables named as "**blogs**",and "**blog_categories**". "**category_id**" which is in "**blog_categories**" having "**primary key**" and "**blog_category**" which is in "**blogs**" having "**foreign key**". Now, I am joining two tables, then sort by category id, then arrange in descending order, then set the limit of 4 are as follow-

```
SELECT * 
FROM blogs 
INNER JOIN blog_categories 
     ON blogs.blog_category = blog_categories.category_id 
WHERE blogs.blog_category ='1' 
ORDER BY blogs.blog_category, blogs.blog_posting_date DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

In this query I have to add one more filter which is that- whatever is to "**blog_id**" (which is in "**blogs**" table) column equivalent to "**blog_category**". And in this all "**blog_category**" only last 4 blog display.

Comment: Are you trying to get one block entry with 4 related blogs in the same category - or 4 blog entries with 4 related blogs each, or simply the 4 latest blog entries (probably by blog_posting_date)?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to get the related blogs. That's why firstly I am filter through blog_category then order by desc and set limit 4. But I have blog_id also which I have to apply on it.

Comment: So, each `blog_category` should have 4 of the last `blog_ig` results by date descending? What is your MySQL version?, run `SELECT @@version;` to check.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/mGdJKV4X

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `row_number() over()` function is what you need,but it can only be used in MySQL version>=8.0

```
select * from 
(select a.*,row_number() over(partition by blog_category order by blog_posting_date desc) rn from blogs where rn <= 4) a 
inner join blog_categories b on a.blog_category = b.category_id
```

mysql5.X:

```
select * from (
select if(@blog_category = a.blog_category, @curRank := @curRank + 1, @curRank := 1) AS rn,@blog_category := a.blog_category, a.* 
from (select * from blogs order by blog_category, blog_posting_date desc) a, 
(select @blog_category := null, @curRank := 0) temp ) m
inner join blog_categories n on m.blog_category = n.category_id
where m.rn<=4
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/er7o_rlg

Comment: this code is not running. I am using phpmyadmin